# Static files not served by express when using pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

im trying to serve up static files using express and pug as the templating engine but somehow my assets are not being loaded

my files path :

```
+front
  +views
   +login
      index.pug
     +images
     +js
     +css
     ...
server.js
```

here is my server code :

```
app.use(express.static('front')); 
app.set('views', './front/views')
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('./Login_v1/login', { title: 'Login', message: 'Login'})    
})
```

pug code  :

```
  link(rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/images/icons/favicon.ico')
```

Answer (score 0):

step first add path to your static folder in app.js/server.js(your entry file of express)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'images/icons')); // path of your image folder
```

than you can access it by

```
href='localhost:serverPort/favicon.ico
```